# RCurl Failed to connect to port 21 FTP Timed out

Tags: r, curl, ftp, rcurl, ftps

I'm in R trying to pull csv data from multiple FTP servers. So far, my code works fine in two of the servers and I'm able to gather the data I need, but a third one throws the folling error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to ftp.ekeystone.com port 21 after 21191 ms: Timed out
```

Here's my code:

```
# required packages
library(RCurl)

# credentials
url <- "ftp.ekeystone.com"
pwd <- "xxxxxxx:yyyyyyyy"

#  recover raw files
rawFiles <- getURL(url = url, userpwd = pwd, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE)
```

It has worked with `ftp://154.49.142.233` and `ftp.motorstateftp.com`, but not with `ftp.ekeystone.com`.

Here is a screenshot that was provided to me as a reference to implement this code.
[image]

Comment: The *"Require implicit FTP over TLS"* is the problem. I do not see TLS enabled in your code, let only the implicit TLS (which uses port 990). I do not known RCurl, so I cannot help further. But I'd start with `url <- "ftps://ftp.ekeystone.com"`

Comment: Thanks Martin, I just tried with `url <- "ftps://ftp.ekeystone.com"` and got `Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Access denied: 530`

Comment: Again, I do not know RCurl, but 530 looks like a code coming from the server. So to me it seems that you got past the problem asked in this question – you are now connected to the server. And you have a new problem. Maybe a wrong path. Or wrong credentials. Anyway, I believe you should ask a new question. Some logs files would help.

Comment: Ok, thanks Martin, I accepted your answer since you say the problem I presented in this question is already solved. Here's the link to the new question in case you have any inputs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77394343/rcurl-cannot-get-files-from-implicit-ftp-over-tls-server-access-denied-error-5. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *"Require implicit FTP over TLS"* is the problem. I do not see TLS enabled in your code, let only the implicit TLS (which uses port 990).

I do not known RCurl. But I'd start with

```
url <- "ftps://ftp.ekeystone.com"
```