# RCurl cannot get files from Implicit FTP over TLS server - Access denied error 530

Tags: r, curl, ftp, rcurl, ftps

I'm in R trying to pull csv data from an FTP server which *"Requires implicit FTP over TLS"*. With some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77394223/12372421) I was able to connect to the server using the following code:

```
# required packages
library(RCurl)

# credentials
url <- "ftps://ftp.ekeystone.com"
pwd <- "xxxxxxx:yyyyyyyy"

#  recover raw files
rawFiles <- getURL(url = url, userpwd = pwd, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Access denied: 530
```

I do not know much about FTP servers, but the person that helped me in the other thread told me this message with 530 code seems like a code coming from the server and thus I'm being able to connect to the server. Not sure what I'd need to do now in order to resolve the access denied problem. Any help much appreciated.

Here is a screenshot that was provided to me as a reference to implement this code.
[image]

Comment: As I have already commented, logs files would be useful (client- or server-side or both)

Comment: I don't know how to provide logs files. My FTP knowledge is quite limited. The only log I have now is the error message. How do I produce any logs file?